# PHP: How do I pass date objects by value?

Tags: php

According to http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php:

> By default, function arguments are passed by value (so that if the value of the argument within the function is changed, it does not get changed outside of the function).

However, when I try the following script, the argument is passed by reference.

```
function test($change_date) {
    $change_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}

$date_initial = new DateTime();
$date_initial->sub(new DateInterval('P30D'));
var_dump($date_initial);
test($date_initial);
var_dump($date_initial);
```

Returns:

```
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>string(19) "2015-03-14 11:19:23"
  ["timezone_type"]=>int()
  ["timezone"]=>string(12)
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>string(19) "2015-03-15 11:19:23"
  ["timezone_type"]=>int()
  ["timezone"]=>string(12)
}
```

So, how do I pass date objects to a function by value so that the original object is not changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable is being passed by value. If you assign to the parameter variable, it won't modify the original variable. Example:

```
function test ($change_date) {
    $change_date = 3;
}
$date_initial = new DateTime();
var_dump($date_initial);
test($date_initial);
var_dump($date_initial);
```

The assignment in the function didn't affect the `$date_initial` value.

However, your `test` function doesn't assign to the variable, it modifies the object. Objects are never automatically copied, so all variables that contain an object will contain the modified object. If you want to make a copy of an object, you have to clone it explicitly:

```
function test($change_date) {
    $change_date = clone $change_date;
    $change_date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/ppBpjC)

Comment: he said he DOESN'T want to modify the original object.

Comment: I know. I'm modifying a clone.

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass object as call by value. Either you will have to instantiate another object inside the function Or you will have to clone existing object.

Check this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php